# Docker - Elasticsearch - Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))

Tags: python, elasticsearch, docker, docker-compose

I'm using `docker-compose` to run python flask app and elasticsearch services in a Linode server.

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    build: config/elastic/
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xms1g -Xmx1g"
    networks:
      - docker_lr
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    networks:
      - docker_lr
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

networks:
  docker_lr:
    driver: bridge
```

Here is the elasticsearch Dockerfile

```
FROM elasticsearch:5

ENV ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Des.path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch"

CMD ["-E", "network.host=0.0.0.0", "-E", "discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes=1"]
```

Here is the **Dockerfile for web**
https://github.com/mysticmode/LibreRead/blob/master/Dockerfile

Both the services are running, which I can check in the browser with my :8000 and :9200

**But I couldn't connect to elasticsearch at :9200 from my python application code.**

```
r = requests.get('http://localhost:9200/lr_index/book_info/_search', data=payload)
```

It is showing this error

```
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9200): Max retries exceeded with url: /lr_index/book_info/_search (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f5b13872250>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

Could someone guide me? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
r = requests.get('http://elasticsearch:9200/lr_index/book_info/_search', data=payload)
```

You are running the `python` code in `web` container right? `localhost` refers to the same container's loopback interface.

Using `userdefined networks` that implement `DNS` for containers in the same network. That's why you can call `elasticsearch` container by its name.

Comment: No :? I'm getting the same error now with host as elasticsearch `ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='elasticsearch', port=9200): Max retries exceeded with url: /_ingest/pipeline/attachment (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f8c2b8fa710>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))`

Comment: Note this: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Comment: Please try to ping elasticsearch inside both containers. Both should succeed.

Comment: Thanks, it's working! I have problems within Dockerfile which I'll try to figure it out myself :)

Comment: what differences `socket_connection or create_connection` ?

Comment: No problem, Feel free to ask :), thats what `stackoverflow` is about.

Comment: This answers how to contact another docker container, but what if you're having this error trying to contact the host (localhost of the host machine)? Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: @TheJKFever: you should use the ip address of the host machine, and make sure elasticsearch is reachable on that interfaces.

Comment: @FarhadFarahi nice! how did/do you know it uses 'userdefined networks' implementing DNS for the docker services?